# Appending to dyanamicly generated element - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I wanted to append bunch of html dropdowns to a row of dynamically generated element.

```
<div class="row row-room cf">
<span class="roomNo">Room <span>1</span></span>
<div class="inputsection adult">
    <i class="small-icon-person"></i>
    <div class="inputbox">
        <div class="custom-select-v3">
            <select>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
            </select>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="inputsection child">
    <i class="small-icon-person-small"></i>
    <div class="inputbox">
        <div class="custom-select-v3">
            <select class="hotel-child-dropDown">
                <option>0</option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  


<div class="specify-wrap">                                                            
   <!--Here i want to add some dropdowns -->
</div>


<i class="small-icon-x-red">remove room</i>
</div>
```

I will clone this entire structure 6 or less time, and once i change the **hotel-child-dropDown** i want to add some more dropdowns to `<div class="specify-wrap">`  the problem what im facing here is, once i change the drop down all the `<div class="specify-wrap">` is getting generated with the same dropdowns on all cloned element.

**My code :**

```
$('.hotel-child-dropDown').each(function(){
    $(this).change(function(){
        var el = $(this).parents('.row').find('.specify-wrap');
        var val = $(this).val();
        el.empty();
        var html = 
                    '<div class="inputsection">'+
                    '  <div class="inputbox childMargin">'+
                    '   <div class="custom-select-v3">'+
                    '       <select>'+
                    '           <option>0</option>'+
                    '           <option>1</option>'+
                    '           <option>2</option>'+
                    '           <option>3</option>'+
                    '           <option>4</option>'+
                    '       </select>'+
                    '       <span></span>'+
                    '   </div>'+
                    ' </div>'+
                    '</div>';

        for(var i=0; i<val; i++)
        {
            el.append(html);
        }
        console.log(val);
    });
});
```

**Fiddle Link :** [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/z3pTL/)
Is there any better solution to overcome this situation??

Comment: can you please create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: What is the desired outcome?

Comment: Can you please explain more what is the problem here?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z3pTL/

Comment: check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3pTL/1/) , what is the problem you are facing , explain.

Comment: @AmitSoni i totally understand what you have done there but please ready my question, im not generating each room structure manually its being generated dynamically...so the solution you provide will fain in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Updated **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3pTL/3/)**

while you are cloning div use `clone(true)`. like this

```
$("#add").on("click",function(){
    var rowDiv = $(".row:first").clone(true);
    rowDiv.insertBefore("#add");
});
```

and instead of using `.each()` , directly attach `change` event on the element.
like this

```
$(".hotel-child-dropDown").on("change",function(){
    var el = $(this).parents('.row').find('.specify-wrap');
    var val = $(this).val();
    el.empty();
    var html = 
                '<div class="inputsection">'+
                '  <div class="inputbox childMargin">'+
                '   <div class="custom-select-v3">'+
                '       <select>'+
                '           <option>0</option>'+
                '           <option>1</option>'+
                '           <option>2</option>'+
                '           <option>3</option>'+
                '           <option>4</option>'+
                '       </select>'+
                '       <span></span>'+
                '   </div>'+
                ' </div>'+
                '</div>';

    for(var i=0; i<val; i++)
    {
        el.append(html);
    }
    console.log(val);
});
```

Comment: Dear Amit, I'm having a strange issue with the above code, it seems to work fine in Fiddle but when i actually try to implement it to my local site, its not working as desired. Now when i change the drop down all the cloned elements `.specify-wrap` is getting effected.